# Gem bundle dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to upgrade to latest `haml` gem. Here is the part of the Gemfile:

```
gem "haml", "~> 4.0.2"
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.4", :group => :development
```

However, it seems that another gem:

```
gem "dj_mon", "~> 1.1.0"
```

requires an older version of `haml`. So when I run `bundle update`, I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "haml":
  In Gemfile:
    dj_mon (~> 1.1.0) ruby depends on
      haml (~> 3.1) ruby

    haml (4.0.2)
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: There's really no way to fix this, you simply have to wait until that gem updates their dependencies to the latest version of haml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dependency conflict. I'm not an expert on this, but it seems to me you have two choices:

1. Update to the latest version of haml which is compatible with dj_mon (I think 3.1.8), and then wait until the maintainers of the gem update its dependencies, at which point the conflict is gone.
2. If you really want to use the latest version of haml, then you could fork the dj_mon gem, update the dependency, run the tests for the gem and if all goes well, you can just replace the dependency with your forked version for the time being.

Hope that helps.